# How can I calculate the longest duration in XQuery?

Tags: max, xquery

I have a problem with an exercise in XQuery. The logic:

- Get the course that has the longest duration.

This is the structure of the xml file:

```
<training>
    <course id="1">
        <start>20170101</start>
        <end>20170401</end>
    </course>
</training>
```

I have done this:

```
for $x in doc("LMSGI06")//course
let $max := max($x/end - $x/start)
return
    <duration>{$max}</duration>
```

And this is the result of my query:

```
<duration>300</duration>
<duration>400</duration>
<duration>400</duration>
<duration>400</duration>
<duration>10000</duration>
```

My query lists the duration of all the courses, but I need only the course that has the longest duration. Note that dates in the XML file have number format, not date format, because of that, I´m trying subtract dates like decimal numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Saxon, then another option is the saxon:highest function:

```
saxon:highest(doc("LMSGI06")//course, 
              function($course) { $course/(end - start) }
             )
```

However, your use of decimal subtraction rather than date/duration subtraction isn't sound. Consider the intervals 20161231-20170101 (one day: decimal difference = 8870) compared with 20170201-20170205 (four days: decimal difference = 4). The second duration is longer, but has a smaller decimal difference. So you should really convert the values to xs:date, and subtract them as xs:date values to get an xs:duration value.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently evaluating `max()` inside of your for loop. The `max()` of a single number is that number.

You could get the `max()` of all the durations, then select the course with that duration:

```
let $doc := doc("LMSGI06")
let $maxDuration := max(
                     for $x in $doc//course
                     return $x/end - $x/start
                    )
return $doc//course[(end - start) eq $maxDuration]
```

Or you could order the courses by their duration, and then select the first one:

```
(
  for $course in doc("LMSGI06")//course
  order by $course/end - $course/start descending
  return $course
)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use *Saxon* but still want to process each `course` only once, you can reimplement the `saxon:highest(...)` function in pure *XQuery 3.0*:

```
declare function local:highest($seq, $key-func) {
  head(
    fold-left($seq, (),
      function($max, $curr) {
        let $key := $key-func($curr)
        return if($max[2] >= $key) then $max else ($curr, $key)
      }
    )
  )
};
```

Converting the date strings to the `xs:date` data type can be done as shown below:

```
declare function local:to-date($str) {
  xs:date(concat(substring($str, 1, 4), '-',
    substring($str, 5, 2), '-', substring($str, 7)))
};
```

With both of those functions, the solution to your exercise with correct date comparisons becomes very simple:

```
local:highest(
  doc("LMSGI06")//course, 
  function($course) {
    local:to-date($course/end) - local:to-date($course/start)
  }
)
```